get no data with message mylist is instance of
I have a class myPerson with name details: name, age, and height.
I need to create a list of names mypeople and add to the list all the class details.
During the program execution, I see: mypeople is instance of.
if I print(p.name) or print(p.age) or print(p.height), then I see the correct data.
It does not matter if I have toString method or do ${p.name} or don't change anything.
The issue occurs with the statement: mypeople.add(MyPerson(name: p.name,age:p.age , height:p.height);
The mypeople is shown as Instance of.
Could you please advise how to address this issue.
Thank You
My code:
PeopleList=[Ana, Ron,Jack, Tom, Lisa, Frank];

class myPerson {
  String name;
  int age;
  int height;
  myPerson({required this.name, required this.age, required this.height});
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

List<myPerson> mypeople = [];

Future<List<myPerson>> getPeople() async {

for(var p in await PeopleList()) {
      if(p.isNotEmpty){  
         mypeople.add(MyPerson(name: p.name,age:p.age , height:p.height);

print(mypeople) //shows mypeople is instance of
print(p.name) //shows correct name
print(p.age) //shows correct age
print(p.height) // shows correct height

   }
  }  
 return mypeople;  
}


What are Ana, Ron, Jack, etc?  Are those instances of some other class?

Can you show the actual code you run?  That code won't compile.

When you print an object, Flutter calls the toString() method on that object. And since you don't implement toString in your myPerson class, you end up with the default Object.toString() implementation, which indeed shows instanceOf <whatEverClassTheObjectIsOf>.
If you want it to print something different, override toString() in your myPerson class.
Here's an updated myPerson class with a minimal toString() method:
class myPerson {
  String name;
  int age;
  int height;

  myPerson({required this.name, required this.age, required this.height});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'myPerson(name: $name, age: $age, height: $height)';
  }
}

Also see, this Dart tutorial on overriding methods, which uses toString in its example.

The comments are useful, but the program shows mypeople is instance of. Please see the details above. If I print individual fields of a class, then I see the correct data. The problem occurs when I do mypeople.add(myPerson());. Thank You

You need to override toString() itself, not create other methods. Also note: please don't substantially change your question, as it makes the question/answer combination incomprehensible for future visitors.

I added an example of what this could look like to my answer.

If you want to print out the values of the properties in your class (myPerson), you will have to specify them in your print method.
For example:
for (var person in mypeople) {
  print('Name: ${person.name}, Age: ${person.age}, Height: ${person.height}');
}

Or you can override the toString method in your class (myPerson) to print out the values of the properties.
class myPerson {
  String name;
  int age;
  int height;
  myPerson({required this.name, required this.age, required this.height});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Name: $name, Age: $age, Height: $height';
  }
}

Then you can print the list of people like this:
for (var person in mypeople) {
  print(person);
}

